# JS insertBefore/preprendTo not working after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div inside a container i want to move out of this container. The HTML is here:

```
<li class="item last">
<div class="product-info" id="product-info">
    <p class="special-price-label" id="special-price-label">
        <span class="price percent-label">
            <span class="percent-label-inner-container">
                <span class="percent-label-label">SPAR</span>
                <span class="percent-label-value">42%</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
</li>
```

I want to move #special-price-label out of the .product-info container so the HTML becomes this:

```
<li class="item last">
<p class="special-price-label" id="special-price-label">
    <span class="price percent-label">
        <span class="percent-label-inner-container">
            <span class="percent-label-label">SPAR</span>
            <span class="percent-label-value">42%</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
<div class="product-info" id="product-info">

</div>
</li>
```

It worked fine with this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
( function($) {
$('#special-price-label').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).parent());
})
} ) ( jQuery );
</script>
```

But after i put some InfiniteScroll with Ajax on the page (it is a category page with products) it doesn't work anymore.

I also tried with this code instead without luck:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#special-price-label" ).prependTo( "li.item" );
});
</script>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `id` must be unique in a HTML page, and for this reason  `$('#special-price-label')` will only select the **first** occurrence of `id="special-price-label"` and ignore the rest. You should `class` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. `id` must be used exactly one time in a page. If there are multiple/repeated instances of some containers/DOM nodes use `class`.
2. `$(document).ready()` fires when the DOM is ready and generally far before any ajax call will ever be made.

Coming to your question, here's what you should do:

1. Wrap your DOM moving operation in a named function
2. Call this function once at DOM `ready` (for initial items at page load)
3. Call this function in the `success` callback of the ajax call

Here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbxmpLaa/3/) which may be helpful, instead of an ajax call, there's a button which will dynamically add more items. You may try similarly for your ajax call.